# How to change the table header background color in Ant Design v5 using a custom theme?

Tags: css, next.js, antd

I'm using Ant Design v5 in my React project and I want to customize the table component's header background color using a custom theme. I have tried various approaches, but none of them seem to work.

I have already set up a custom theme by following the official documentation and it is working for other components, but I can't seem to figure out how to target the table header specifically.

Can anyone provide a code snippet or guidance on how to change the background color of the table header in Ant Design v5 using a custom theme?

There are some more issues I'm facing with

Button -> fontWeightStrong is not working
Input -> How do I define Input for text and password separately using custom theme at global level
Table -> borderRadius, boxShadow is also not working

```
const customTheme: ThemeConfig = {
  token: {
    colorPrimary: 'red',
  },
  components: {
    Input: {
      colorFill: 'green',
      colorError: 'yellow',
      colorBorder: 'red',
      colorInfoHover: 'red',
    },
    Table: {
      borderRadius: 20,
      colorFillContent: 'green',
      boxShadow: '5px 8px 24px 5px rgba(208, 216, 243, 0.6)',
      colorTextHeading: 'red',
      colorHighlight: 'blue',
      colorBgContainer: 'pink',
      colorFillSecondary: 'purple',
    },
    Button: {
      fontWeightStrong: 900,
    },
  },
};
```

I'm using typescript so when I use tableHeaderBg it doesn't allow me to use it.